# How to run progress bar widget from dask.distributed in a separate thread?

Tags: python, distributed, jupyter-notebook, dask

There is an example [here](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/queues.html), showing insertion of data for processing in a separate thread. I'm interested in reverse, when data are inserted manually and interactively, and background thread submits them to cluster for calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already the case.  When you call

```
client.submit(function, *args, **kwargs)
```

This serializes stuff immediately in the local thread (blocking), but then adds a callback to the Tornado IOLoop (running in a separate thread) to manage the actual communication to the scheduler.  This all happens asynchronously to the main thread.